# Visual Studio for Mac trying to find .NET Full Framework in build properties

Tags: .net-5

Visual Studio for Mac (Version 8.8.7 (build 18)) is unable to upgrade netcoreapp3.1 asp.net mvc project to .net5.0 target framework. It throws below error:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.405/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(5,5):
> Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'App.Mvc/project.assets.json' doesn't
> have a target for '.NETFramework,Version=v5.0'. Ensure that restore
> has run and that you have included 'net50' in the TargetFrameworks for
> your project. (NETSDK1005) (App.Mvc)

It will create a net5.0 mvc project from scratch alright but upgrade fails with the error. I've also tried to move all the files over into a new net5.0 from my netcoreapp3.1 project and somehow it converts the new project to .net full framework again. There's no clear indication as to what's causing this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I had a global.json pointing to version 3.1.*. Had 5.0.102 and it worked.

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. `.NET Full Framework` is the *old*, Windows-only framework that can't work on Mac

Comment: Thanks. Having spent 22+ years of my life in .net and asp.net (since its inception v1.0) I'm at least expected to know that (and i do!) ;). I was stunned with how the vs for mac was pointing to .net full framework as target framework even when the TFM was set to net5.0. I didn't think vs for mac would ever show anything related to .net full framework but i guess I was wrong.